# Create new text file with sum of third column of several others

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have several different text files of the format:

```
x y z

x y z

x y z
```

I want to create a new file which sums the `z` values in each, and then has the summed value in place of `z` i.e.

```
x y (z1+z2+z3+z4)

x y (z1+z2+z3+z4)

x y (z1+z2+z3+z4)
```

How can I do this from the command line? I'm aware of `awk` but not entirely sure how to use it for this purpose, or if that would in fact be the most efficient method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the concatenated files to `awk` twice, first time (`NR==FNR`) to calculate the `sum` of third column (`$3`) in all files and the second time to replace the existing values with the total:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{sum+=$3;next}; {$3=sum; print}' <(cat file1 file2...fileN) \
<(cat file1 file2...fileN) > result.txt
```